# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 30 out of bounds for length 30

Tags: java, arrays, processing

UPDATE: Turns out I had to export an SVG again and put it in the data folder of my file.

Yet again I'm faced with a coding question.
Apologies if this is not correctly formatted, I have yet to improve my way of phrasing coding questions.

What does ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : Index 30 out of bounds for length 30 mean? I already tried to look it up myself but I can't seem to find the meaning.

At first when I added my svg's, the code was working , then I added the same files again and also that was working ( Eye2,pupil2,lash2), then I added the Nose.SVG file and I suddenly got an error.

I'm coding in processing 4.0

And this is the error I get, also I have copy-pasted all my code.

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 30 out of bounds for length 30

-- I can't seem to find my stacktrace

```
PShape Eye;
PShape Pupil;
PShape Lash;
PShape Eye2;
PShape Pupil2;
PShape Lash2;
PShape Mouth;
PShape Line;
PShape Nose;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000);
  Eye = loadShape("Eye.svg");
  Pupil= loadShape("Pupil.svg");
  Lash= loadShape("Lash.svg");
  Mouth= loadShape("Mouth.svg");
  Line= loadShape("Line.svg");
  Nose= loadShape("Nose.svg");
  Eye2 = loadShape("Eye.svg");
  Pupil2= loadShape("Pupil.svg");
  Lash2= loadShape("Lash.svg");
}

void draw() {
  background(230, 230, 250);

  shape(Nose, 110, 90, 200, 200);


  Eye.disableStyle();
  fill( 173, 216, 230);
  stroke( 173, 216, 230);
  shape(Eye, 110, 90, 400, 400);


  Pupil.disableStyle();
  fill( 255, 140, 0);
  stroke( 255, 140, 0);
  shape(Pupil, 220, 200, 200, 200);

  shape(Lash, 90, 10, 400, 400);


  Eye2.disableStyle();
  fill( 173, 216, 230);
  stroke( 173, 216, 230);
  shape(Eye2, 500, 90, 400, 400);


  Pupil2.disableStyle();
  fill( 255, 140, 0);
  stroke( 255, 140, 0);
  shape(Pupil2, 620, 200, 200, 200);

  shape(Lash2, 500, 10, 400, 400);


  Mouth.disableStyle();
  fill(192, 238, 144);
  stroke(192, 238, 144);
  shape(Mouth, 280, 400, 400, 450);

  shape(Line, 280, 400, 350, 350);
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and show the complete error stack.  thanks

Comment: Please add the stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

The *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : Index 30 out of bounds for length 30* means that you have an array with length 30 and trying to access an element at index 30. But the valid index range is 0-29.

From the code above is not possible to see where from the exception is comming.